# CakePHP Auth redirect method redirects me to /users/img/favicon.png?

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to using the default behavior of the AuthComponent in CakePHP but I get a strange behavior from it when I try to use the method `$this->Auth->redirect()` in the `login` action.

I would like to redirect the logged user to the `view` where he previously been redirected from like [CakePHP log in redirect to requested URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964183/cakephp-log-in-redirect-to-requested-url) article. I've also read `CakePHP 1.3` [Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1250/Authentication#loginRedirect-12709) without understand where I'm wrong.

Here is my code:

AppController

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authError' => 'Error message',
        'authorize' => array(
            'Controller',
            'Actions' => array(
                'actionPath' => 'controllers'
            )
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

UsersController

```
public function login () {
    if ($this->request->is ('post')){
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $auth_user = $this->Auth->user();
            $this->User->id = $auth_user['id'];
            $this->User->saveField('last_login', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            $this->Session->write('flash_element','done');
            $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome back <b>'.$auth_user['username'].'</b>!');

            $this->redirect ($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->set('flash_element','warning');
            $this->Session->setFlash('Wrong login');
        }
    }
}
```

This setting redirects me to `http://site.com/users/img/favicon.png`
If I `debug` the `$this->Auth->redirect()` i get exactly `/users/img/favicon.png` string.

I tried to comment a line in the `default.ctp` layout file and after it `everything works perfect`, why?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title><?php echo $title_for_layout; ?></title>

        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <?php
        echo $this->Html->css('style.css');
        //echo $this->Html->meta('icon','img/favicon.png');
        ...
```

I didn't get why this line breaks my `AuthComponent`, is the favicon code wrong?

The rest of the application works flawlessly with all models, views and controllers.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the favicon without using Cake's Html Helper? Like this: <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.png"> Do you still get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing scaffolding from the Users controller and baking it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the 'loginRedirect' key in your AuthComponent setting:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action => 'view'),
        'authError' => 'Error message',
        'authorize' => array(
            'Controller',
            'Actions' => array(
                'actionPath' => 'controllers'
            )
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Also `$this->Auth->login()` should auto-magically redirect you.

Comment: I've tried it without changes to the problem, I really don't know what I've done to get this problem!

Comment: Do you get some kind of an error in the web server logs? `$this->redirect ($this->Auth->redirect());` has a space between $this->redirect and the ()s. Also check if you have any whitespace at the beginnings or ends of files such as app_controller, the controller you're in.